# JTAppleCalendarView show selectedview when deselect item

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, jtapplecalendar

When i select date and then i select another date selectedview visible on previous selected date

```
let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(
            startDate: startDate,
            endDate: endDate,
            numberOfRows: 6,
            calendar: calendar,
            generateOutDates: .tillEndOfRow,
            firstDayOfWeek: .monday
        )

        return parameters
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

actually code was fine i was getting some error due to xcode issue i had tested on real  device and it was working fine